# Has someone an example string to connect using parity?

Tags: parity

I have a geth connection as follows -

> geth --datadir ~/blockchain/mybc1 --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" 
>   --rpcport 8545 --unlock "0x0c12901e1ec7f80763cd433e8eca0c837d11a0c1" --rpc --networkid 1234 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" console 2> consolemybc1.log

I read the docs for parity but I could not find a clear example and there are a lot of options with parity.

How would I convert this into connecting with the parity client aside from changing geth to parity?

Answer (score 1):

## Starting parity

Start up parity, for example:

```
parity -d /opt/parity --no-ancient-blocks
```

## Attaching to it

Run geth to attach to parity:

```
geth attach /opt/parity/jsonrpc.ipc
```

Comment: I was trying to use a private network, is RPC still specified in the connection string?

Comment: Sure, just use the `--chain=<chain>` flag to parity. You can specify any of: `olympic`, `frontier`, `homestead`, `mainnet`, `morden`, `ropsten`, `classic`, `expanse`, `musicoin`, `testnet`, `kovan` or `dev`. You probably want `dev`